# PHP loop throwing notice, which seems to be a constant error

Tags: php, error-handling, notice

```
$features[] = array("Feature 1", "Feature 2", "Feature 3", "Feature 4")

for ($i=0; $i <4 ; $i++) {
echo '<li class="list-group-item text-centre">'.  $features[i] . '</li>';
```

I am unable to resolve the notice:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant i - assumed 'i' in /home3/..../public_html/html......com/all/stripe/index.php on line 48
```

Comment: `$features[$i]` will do the magic.

Comment: It says now : Notice: Undefined variable: i

Comment: Just remove `[]` from `$features[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cause of `$features[]`.
Use:

```
$features = array("Feature 1", "Feature 2", "Feature 3", "Feature 4")
```

`$features[]` means that you're passing a value after `=` into a new index of `$features` array, i.e. `$features[0][your_array]`

And

`echo '<li class="list-group-item text-centre">'`.  $features[**$i**] . `'</li>'`;

replace it with

```
echo '<li class="list-group-item text-centre">'.  $features[$i] . '</li>';
```

Comment: This worked: echo '<li class="list-group-item text-centre">'. $features[$i] . '</li>';

Comment: @wocommerce115, yeap, after the first one replace it works, yes, without it you need to use [0].